# Contact ID error during export

Tags: export

We are trying to export to CSV but of our 15,000 records, approx 4000 of them are showing an incorrect contact ID (somehow the contact IDs have got mixed up so the name and email etc. is showing for a different contact ID as when you do a look up search.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question so someone can answer?

Comment: Are you saying that when you look at Contact ID 27 in civicrm it shows John Smith but when you export it then John Smith has the ID 54 (which really can't happen in the export). Are you sure you are exporting the Contact ID and not the External ID (or the User ID)? Maybe add some screenshots of one example to your question

Comment: Thank you. It appears we can't be sure if the duplication has happened during civi export or subsequent manipulation. I think we should leave this enquiry here but thanks for trying to help.